# I am Trying to connect to an existing BizTalk application and add Receive Ports and Send Ports and Parties etc

Tags: powershell, biztalk

**When run this I do not get a error, but when I create send ports and Receive locations I don't see anything**

**make sure the ExplorerOM assembly is loaded**

```
[void]   [System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadwithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")
```

## Connect to the BizTalk management database

```
    $Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
    $Catalog.ConnectionString = "SERVER=sql\instance;      DATABASE=BizTalkMgmtDb; Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

**Connect to an existing application in Biztalk**
**Create a message to let you know if powershell can't find the applicaiton on your server**
 **If it can't find the application it gives a error and discard changes. If so it continues**

```
    $In837_2Cimor = $Catalog.Applications["In837_2Cimor"]

        if ($In837_2Cimor -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host "`r`nFailed to find `"In837_2Cimor`" deployed on this BizTalk server."
    }
    else
    {

    **Register a trap handler for any exceptions**
   $ErrorActionPreference="silentlycontinue"
    trap { "Exception encountered:`r`n"; $_; "`r`nDiscarding Changes.`r`n";$Catalog.DiscardChanges();exit; }
    }



**Create a new receive port named For the new provider**
```

**And A new receive location will also be created and associated**
**with the receive port.**

```
$NewRP = $In837_2Cimor.AddNewRecievePort($false,$false)
    $NewRP.Name = "RP_Pickup999_000"
```

**Note if you don’t set the name property for the receive port,**
   **it will create a new receive location and add it to the receive**
  **port.**

```
**Create a new receive location and add it to the receive port**
    $NewRL = $In837_2Cimor.AddNewReceiveLocation($false,$false)
    $NewRL.PrimaryTransport.TransportType = $Catalog.ProtocolTypes["FILE"]
    $NewRL.PrimaryTransport.Address = "\\location\BizTalkd\"
    $NewRL.SendPipeline = $Catalog.Pipelines["Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.PassThruTransmit"]

**Save the changes**
    Write-Host "Adding $NewRP.Name..."
    $catalog.SaveChanges();
            Write-Host "`r`n $NewRP.Name has been created."
```

**Create New In837 sendPorts for a new provider**

```
$NewSP = $In837_2Cimor.AddNewSendPort($false,$false)
    $NewSP.Name = "SP_999_TO_FTP_000"
    $NewSP.PrimaryTransport.TransportType = $Catalog.ProtocolTypes["FILE"]
    $NewSP.SendHandler = $Catalog.SendHandlers["BizTalkServerApplication"]
    $NewSP.PrimaryTransport.Address = "\\location\"
    $NewSP.SendPipeline = $Catalog.Pipelines["Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.PassThruTransmit"]
```

**Add the filter to New send port**

```
$NewSP.Filter = "<Filter><Group>" +
                 "<Statement Property='BTS.ReceivePortName' Operator='==' Value='RP_Pickup999_000'/>" +
                 "</Group></Filter>"
    Write-Host Adding ($NewSP.Name) and ($NewRP.Name) and ($NewRL.Name) to catalog...
    $Catalog.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: When run this I do not get a error, but when I create send ports and Receive locations I don't see anything?

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please use the [edit] link below the question to add new details, rather than in the comments where it is overlooked.   Also when posting code, please either select the code and use the {} button to indent all code by 4 spaces or use the triple backtick before and after to format it as code.  Also your code doesn't have any actions to create ports, all it is doing is finding the host.  Please add the code that should add the ports,

Comment: @Dijkgraaf do you know why?